# Make lines in .vtp file

Tags: graph, vtk, paraview

I want to visualize a graph in 3d in paraview. This requires me to have points and edges connecting the points. I know how to make the points but can't seem to figure out how to make the edges.

Currently I can make .vtp files with points and associated vectors. I want to know how to modify my .vtp files to include these edges as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So the file format section of [VTKUsersGuide](https://www.kitware.com/products/books/VTKUsersGuide.pdf) does not help ? A more hacky way would be to write a PLY file and then convert it to .vtp [with vtk](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python/Convert_PLY_to_VTP).

Comment: As @GabrielDevillers suggested, the users guide documents .vtp files (Section 19.3), which does in fact support lines. I also find it helpful to use ParaView to make an example file. Try opening ParaView, create a line source, and then save the data to a .vtp file. (I usually write the data in ASCII mode in these small examples because it is easier to eyeball.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using paraview to make .vtp files @KennethMoreland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a vtkLineSource:

```
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource> lineSource = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLineSource>::New();
  lineSource->SetPoint1(p0);
  lineSource->SetPoint2(p1);
  lineSource->Update();
```

`lineSource->GetOutput()` will give you a polydata that you can then write with a `vtkXMLPolyDataWriter`. See a full example here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Line